# How to add multiple parameters to Socket.io while sending an event?

Tags: ios, objective-c, socket.io

I am currently working on socket.io framework, to trigger an event to server we have a predefined method that is sendEvent with eventName and data, my question is what if we want to send multiple arguments like,
sendEvent with eventName data1 and data2, how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send more than one piece of data, you can put the multiple pieces into an array or an object and pass the array or object to `emit()`.  socket.io will turn it into JSON, send the JSON and then parse the JSON at the other end back into the object or array.

Comment: thank you for your response, can i have your mail id for further discussion. else mail me at kiran.kumar39@gmail.com

Comment: @krishna - that is not generally how this site works.  If you don't fully understand this answer, you can add a comment and ask for some clarification.  My participation is here, not in private email.

Comment: @jfriend00-please show me the framework in which socket is having emit function in relation with objective c , not in swift.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify what @jfriend00 is getting at, here is a more concrete example...

```
if (_socket.status == SocketIOClientStatusConnected)
    [_socket emit:@"aMessage" 
             with:@[ @{      @"aKey"  : @(9999), 
                        @"anotherKey" : @"someValue } ]];
```

in your (`coffeescript`) socket.io server you may have something similar to...

```
app = require('http').createServer()
io = require('socket.io')(app)

io.sockets.on 'connection', (socket) ->
    socket.on 'aMessage', (data) ->
    console.log 'got data', data

app.listen 8900
```

which would result in something like...

> `got data aKey: 9999, anotherKey: "someValue"`

tldr;

Your `with:`"array" can really just be a single object... but it can be a dictionary, with multiple keys and values.